# Using selectors/filters on external collections - possible?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have a simple function that hides/shows nodes via a supplied filter parameter and the removal part works fine.  However I'm unable to apply the same filter on the collection of nodes I've already removed so I can restore just those ones. *(Cytoscape newbie and my Javascript-fu is weak...)*

```
  var hiddenOnes = cy.collection();

  var hideShow = function(selectorExpr, event) {

    if (event.target.checked == true) {
        var restoring = hiddenOnes(selectorExpr);  // problem is here!
        cy.add(restoring);
        } else {
            var nodesToHide = cy.nodes(selectorExpr);
            hiddenOnes = hiddenOnes.union( nodesToHide.remove() );
            }       
  }
```

I understand *why* the selector expression can't be used on the hiddenOnes collection, I just want to know how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

`hiddenOnes` can not be used like `hiddenOnes(selector)`.  Use `hiddenOnes.filter(selector)`.

Refer to the docs: https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.filter

And the Chrome debugger docs are useful for identifying certain types of problems: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/